# Django admin - return the text from a forgeign key as display name

Tags: django

I want to have the display name of my drop down in the admin panel to be the location title from the parent model. by default the list shows "SNMPData Object" for all items in the list.

however I want to show the site name, I thought it was as simple as adding self.location but that is throwing the error

error:

```
coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, MajorSiteInfoData found
```

code:

```
class MajorSiteInfoData(models.Model):
    Location = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    class Meta:
            verbose_name = "Major Site Locations"
            verbose_name_plural = "Major Site Locations"      

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.Location

class SNMPData(models.Model):   
    Location = models.ForeignKey(MajorSiteInfoData)
    SNMP_AUTH = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    SNMP_PRIV = models.CharField(max_length=200)   

    class Meta:
            verbose_name = "SNMP Data"
            verbose_name_plural = "SNMP Data"  

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.Location
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `__unicode__` function needs to return a string of what you want to show. Your function should look like:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.Location.Location
```

One thing to improve, you shouldn't use the same field names for different models, you might quickly confuse yourself because sometimes you need `Location` and sometimes you need `Location.Location` as above. Rename the foreign key to be something else like `major_site_info`. Also use lower cases with underscores for field names, Camel cases are for class names in python.

Comment: thanks, if i change all the model names, will i need to run a sqlmigrate?

Comment: Your model names are fine, your field names are not that compliance to PEP8. If you decided to change the field names, you need to create a django migration to do this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/migration-operations/#renamefield.